# Voltage regulator not working

Tags: mosfet, power-supply

I am trying to generate 5 V here, but I am getting only 3.3 V. I can see the drop across Q3 is more than 2 V. Can someone suggest what the error is?

Also, what changes should I make to replace Q3 with an N-channel MOSFET? load current is 100mA

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do in this circuit. You say "I am trying to generate 5 V here", but you have a 5V voltage source (as well as other voltages) in your circuit already. So what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes current conducts through Drain to Source when the body diode is forward biased.

Comment: I can't know what the voltage drop is if you don't say which FET you will use. Rds(on) has nothing to do with it if the FET is not conducting but the diode is.

Comment: The diode forward voltage will be 0.7V to 1.2V with 1A current and VGS=0V. Datasheet includes a curve just for the diode too.

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast - Hi, On Stack Exchange it is not allowed to add more questions in comments, so your follow-up question here has been deleted. I see you have asked it as a [separate question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701318/p-channel-mosfet-lighting-protection). FYI Stack Exchange has different rules to typical forums. Please see the [tour] & [help] for details of the main site rules & etiquette.